# Replacing non-pure virtual functions with CRTP

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, crtp

I'm writing plugins for an application through its C++ SDK. The mechanism is fairly simple. A plugin provides its functionality through predefined interfaces. This is done by having server classes inherit from one implementation class per interface, which contains either pure vitual functions or non-pure functions with default implementations.
This is very practical as SDK clients only have to override those methods that the plugin requires and/or provide an implementation for the (rare) ones with no default.

What has been bugging me is that everything is known at compile time. The virtual function tables and machinery associated with runtime polymorphism are here only for the sake of providing default implementations.
I'm attempting to remove this overhead while keeping the convenience.

As a (very contrived) example, say I have a couple of servers presenting a single interface (named Blah) consisting of only one method with no default implementation.

```
// SDK header
struct OldImpl_Blah {
    virtual ~OldImpl_Blah() =default;
    virtual int mult(int) =0;
};

// plugin source
class OldServer3 : public OldImpl_Blah {
public:
    int mult(int i) override { return 3 * i; }
};

class OldServer5 : public OldImpl_Blah {
public:
    int mult(int i) override { return 5 * i; }
};
```

For pure virtual functions, straight forward CRTP works just fine.

```
// SDK header
template <typename T>
struct NewImpl_Blah {
    int mult(int i) { return static_cast<T*>(this)->mult(i); }
};

// plugin source
class NewServer3 : public NewImpl_Blah<NewServer3> {
public:
    int mult(int i) { return 3 * i; }
};

class NewServer5 : public NewImpl_Blah<NewServer5> {
public:
    int mult(int i) { return 5 * i; }
};
```

The problem is with *non*-pure virtual functions, i.e. when there is a default implementation for the method.

```
// SDK header
struct OldImpl_Blah {
    virtual ~OldImpl_Blah() =default;
    virtual int mult(int i) { return i; }    // default
};

// plugin source
class OldServer3 : public OldImpl_Blah {
public:
    int mult(int i) override { return 3 * i; }
};

class OldServer5 : public OldImpl_Blah {
public:
    int mult(int i) override { return 5 * i; }
};
```

I tried to combine CRTP with some expression SFINAE trickery and failed.
I guess what I need is some kind of code dispatching where the base class would either provide a default implementation or forward its arguments to the implementation in the derived class, if it exists.
The problem seems to be that the dispatch should rely on information that is not yet available to the compiler in the base class.

A simple solution would be to just remove the `virtual` and `override` keywords in the code. But then the compiler wouldn't check that the function signatures match.
Is there some well known pattern for this situation? Is what I'm asking possible at all?

(Please use small words as my expertise with templates is a bit on the light side. Thanks.)

Comment: What version of C++ are you able to compile under?

Comment: "the compiler wouldn't check that the function signatures match". Can you show, by providing a code sample, what undesirable effects this could have?

Comment: @AndyG: I'm using VS 2015 update 1. Would that be C++14?

Comment: @n.m.: I'm not sure I understand your question. If the user makes a typo in the name for example, it would create a new function.

Comment: There are no equivalent of "override" keyword for CRTP (to indicate desire to hide non-virtual member function of base class with same signature). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: OK I think I've got your idea. See my answer. Note CRTP is said to eliminate the virtual call overhead because it does not require functions to be `virtual`. I have no idea if it still eliminates the overhead with the `virtual` specifier left in place (or if there's any overhead worth eliminating, but that's a different story). See my answer, it shows how to do CRTP while keeping a default implementation.

Comment: In theory using `final` keyword with `override` enables compiler to dispatch more optimally than vtable approach.

Comment: @Utkarsh: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier, it was hidden. I've no idea how good at devirtualizing current compilers are. Last time I read about it, it was in its infancy. If `final` makes the vtables go away, then it's great. The SDK provides an `OVERRIDE` macro (from the time when not all compilers supported the keyword yet). If adding `final` to it  does the job, it's perfect as it would require no change whatsoever in client code. More testing... :)

Answer (score 3):

As always, Yet Another Level of Indirection is the solution. In this particular case, it's the well known technique of public non-virtual functions calling private or protected virtual functions. It have its own uses, independent of what is being discussed here, so check it out regardless. Normally it works like this:

```
struct OldImpl_Blah {
piblic:
    virtual ~OldImpl_Blah() = default;
    int mult(int i) { return mult_impl(i); }
protected:
    virtual int mult_impl(int i) { return i; }
};

// plugin source
class OldServer3 : public OldImpl_Blah {
protected:
    int mult_impl(int i) override { return 3 * i; }
};
```

With CRTP it's exactly the same:

```
template <class T>
struct OldImpl_Blah {
piblic:
    virtual ~OldImpl_Blah() = default;
    int mult(int i) { return static_cast<T*>(this)->mult_impl(i); }
protected:
    virtual int mult_impl(int i) { return i; }
};

// plugin source
class OldServer3 : public OldImpl_Blah<OldServer3> {
protected:
    int mult_impl(int i) override { return 3 * i; }
};
```

Disclaimer: CRTP is said to eliminate virtual call overhead by nit requiring functions to be `virtual`. I don't know if CRTP has any performance benefits when functions are kept `virtual`.

Comment: I believe, OP is trying to avoid virtual calls altogether. And in my vier, combining CRTP with virtual calls is an abomination.

Comment: @SergeyA I believe OP wants to keep the functions virtual, but believes CRTP will remove the overhead. I have no idea if this is the case (or whether there's any overhead worth eliminating, but that's another story). The technique above works equally well if all `virtual` keywords are removed.

Comment: @ n.m.: Thanks for your answer but no, I don't want to keep the virtual functions. Conceptually, there's no need for them as objects of server types are not manipulated through a common base type. As I said, they are only used to provide default implementations.

Comment: So just remove the virtual keyword in the above implementation.

Comment: @Garp n.m. is right. Even though I get fun in trying to solve it (see my answer), if you do not plan to use them by means of base classes you can simply drop the virtual keyword. Let the methods in the derived classes hide the one defined in the base class and that's all.

Comment: 'just remove the virtual keyword'. Indeed :) I'll have to test some more to make sure all uses are covered.  If it's the case, this seems to be by far the simplest solution. I'll also have to check the output. Ideally, I'd want a compille-time selection of the code so that either the user-provided implementation or the default one ends up in the binary, but not both. In any case, I'm learning a lot here.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I'm not sure I'd use the following code, but I think it does what the OP is asking for.
This is a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

template<class D>
struct B {
    template <typename T>
    struct hasFoo {
        template<typename C>
        static std::true_type check(decltype(&C::foo));

        template<typename>
        static std::false_type check(...);

        static const bool value = decltype(check<T>(0))::value;
    };

    int foo() {
        return B::foo<D>(0, this);
    }

private:
    template<class T>
    static auto foo(int, B* p) -> typename std::enable_if<hasFoo<T>::value, int>::type {
        std::cout << "D::foo" << std::endl;
        return static_cast<T*>(p)->foo();
    }

    template<class T>
    static auto foo(char, B*) -> typename std::enable_if<not hasFoo<T>::value, int>::type {
        std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
        return 42;
    }
};

struct A: B<A> { };

struct C: B<C> {
    int foo() {
        std::cout << "C::foo" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    B<A> *ba = new A;
    ba->foo();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    C c;
    c.foo();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    B<C> *bc = new C;
    bc->foo();
}
```

If I did it right, there are no virtual methods, but the right implementation of `foo` is called, no matter if you are using a base class or a derived one.
Of course, it is designed around the CRTP idiom.

I know, the member detector class is far from being good.
Anyway, it's enough for the purpose of the question, so...

Comment: Thank you, skypjack. I'll look deeper into it tomorrow (it's way past  bedtime here).

Comment: @Garp You are welcome. Let me know if it works as expected. I'm not sure I fully understand the question. If you need more details, feel free to ask and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Since you are using modern C++ (tell-tale `decltype`), I suggest you move away from C++03 - check functions and adopt `void_t`.

Comment: @SergeyA I failed trying to figure out what do you mean with *adopt void_t*!! I slightly changed the member detector (it uses now `std::true/false_type`), but I'm curious to know what you have in mind...

Comment: @skypjack: The code does what I want, thanks for that. I'll have to check the assembly to make sure it's not replacing the overhead of virtuals with another one. Also this is a very simple example. The SDK (a library, really) contains about 3000 methods across 300 interfaces, roughly. I'd like a more compact way to do the selection (ideally at compile time). I too was thinking about void_t when looking at the code but my memory is a little fuzzy. I'll have to review Walter Brown's slides from his  2-part talk at ccpcon 2014.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using something like policy design:

```
struct DefaultMult {
    int mult(int i) { return i; }
};

// SDK header
template <typename MultPolicy = DefaultMult>
struct NewImpl_Blah {
    int mult(int i) { return multPolicy.mult(i); }
  private:
    MultPolicy multPolicy;
};

// plugin source
class NewServer3 {
public:
    int mult(int i) { return 3 * i; }
};

class NewServer5 {
public:
    int mult(int i) { return 5 * i; }
};

void client() {
  NewImpl_Blah<NewServer5> myServer;
}
```

Also note that in theory using `final` keyword with `override` enables compilers to dispatch more optimally than vtable approach. I expect modern compilers to optimise if you use `final` keyword in your first implementation.

Some helpful refs:

- [mixin design](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/C%20%20_Mixins_-_Reuse_through_inheritance_is_good)
- For more on policy based design you can watch video or read book / article by Andrei Alexandrescu

Comment: Note that the title of the question says *with CRTP*.

Comment: Yeah, that is true but if the motive is to skip vtable overhead and have option for using different implementations along with a default one then Policy design fits better than CRTP. IMHO, policy design can be a cleaner solution for most of these tasks.

Comment: Despite what the title said, I'm not hell bent on CRTP. The idea is to get that slow SDK to run faster (it's for a 3D app where plugins might have to deal with collections of millions of objects). I'm not familiar with the policy design. I'm afraid it would require substantially more work from the SDK's clients. It's definitely intriguing and I'll look more into it.

Comment: @Garp well, I'd suggest to change the title of create a new question if you are looking for general solutions that shouldn't involve CRTP as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, I understand what you are trying to do. If I am correct in my understanding, that can't be done.

Logically, you would want to have `mult` in `Base` to check if `mult` is present in the child struct - and if it does, call it, if it does not, provide some default implementation. The flaw here is that there **always** be `mult` in child class - because it will inherit implementation of checking `mult` from Base. Unavoidably.

The solution is to name function differently in the child class, and in the base check for presence of differently named function - and call it. This is a simple thing to do, let me know if you'd like the example. But of course, you will loose the beauty of override here.

Comment: Actually, the functions in my derived classes in the CRTP version where named `my_mult`. I'm not sure why I changed the name. To check in the base class that `my_mult` is present in the derived class, I turned `mult` into a template function with a single unnamed template parameter defaulted to something like `decltype(static_cast<T*>(this)->my_mult(0))`. This didn't work. My guess is that SFINAE systematicly kicks in due to the compiler not knowing anything about `my_mult` yet.

Comment: @Garp, I have a working example of sfinae checking for differently named function (without override, of course). If you want, i can post it tomorrow.

Comment: That could be very useful indeed. Thanks :) I'm not sure it would work though. My understanding of CRTP is that it works only because the evaluation of the function call after the static cast to derived happens during instanciation, at which point the compiler knows the base class _and_ the derived class. It looks like SFINAE checks are performed during the first pass so the compiler wouldn't know the derived class, let alone what member functions it has. It feels like an egg-and-chicken problem.

Comment: Garp, @skypjack already provided a working answer. I would do it slightly differently, but this is a working solution you can use, so I see no reason to duplicate it.